# Domain Name is not sticking on application summary

Tags: facebook, dns, facebook-like

I added a like button to my site pages.  It seems to work, but the debugger is giving me errors.  When I try out the URL in the Object Debugger it gives the error below:

Object Base Domain Not Allowed  Object at URL 'http://www.gdiy.com/projects/visiting-paris/index.php' of type 'website' is invalid because the domain 'www.gdiy.com' is not allowed for the specified application id '279134608772109'.

When I try adding the domain name in the facebook developer apps settings (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) it is not sticking.

I enter "gdiy.com" as the domain and press enter -> then save.  If I refresh the page now the domain doesn't exist anymore.

Debugger results page:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gdiy.com%2Fprojects%2Fvisiting-paris%2Findex.php

What's wrong here?  I even tried "www.gdiy.com" and that didn't work either.  I also waited a couple hours before trying.

Comment: Seeing the same problem today - after the page reloads the App Domains are listed, but if you navigate away and come back to the Basic Settings page the input is blank.  Previously, multiple domains were not supported but and they may have introduced a bug when adding this feature.

Comment: This did the trick for me: 

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616965/facebook-app-domain-dissapears 

(sic)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I waited a day, came back, and it seemed to be fixed. I'm not sure if this was a Facebook bug that they fixed, or if there was something else weird going on. However, time seemed to do the trick this time.

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome and doesn't work, and I try with Firefox and work it!