# Facebook App Domain disappears

Tags: facebook, dns, comments

I've added a comment box to my site. I'm using an app_id. I've added my domain to "App Domain" in the settings section for the app. I save it. I then come back and the "App Domain" has disappeared. It's like it's not being saved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem - Did you find a solution? Seemed to pick a buggy day to try to set this up...

Answer (score 30):

I found how to do this - the UI and error messages are simply terrible.
First, you need to set your site url in the website section - to eg http://www.example.com . Click Save

Then you can go to the app domain field, type 'example.com' and press enter - it should highlight. You can do the same to add more domains.

This managed to get them to stick for me.

Comment: This is correct. You have to enter in a web site URL (even if you're not making a stand alone web site that people can go to - or at least that you advertise). 

So for example you want JUST a tab for a FB page. You can specify the tab URLs, but you can not get the dialog popups using the JavaScript SDK until that page's domain is authorized in your Facebook app. 

I think it SHOULD let you add the app domain values if a tab URL is set, but it doesn't. It may be a bug on Facebook's part. So you just have to enter in a Website as well for now even if you don't intend to have a stand alone site.

Comment: This set me back a day.  Thanks for finally solving it!

Comment: Note that just entering a Mobile Web URL is not enough either - I had to also enter a Website Site URL.

Comment: Facebook should have a check on this. This is really a pain to figure out. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'm honestly amazed that this is still a problem people are having - once you figure it out it's OK but facebook really needs to fix the settings page.

Answer (score 2):

you must fill Site URL first, after that you can fill the App Domain
Sorry if my english is suck

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that Facebook is buggy today (cough).

Another thing to check is the Roles section to ensure your current FB user is in the Administrators list.  You should be, of course, but I know folks who have different users for different purposes and they get mixed up as to which one they're logged in as.  Just an idea.

Edit:  Also, on the Advanced settings page you can control your App Type.  Is it still set to Web?  Since the domain is less relevant for Native/Desktop, I could see them ignoring your input if it's configured that way.