# facebook developer 'app domains' not saving

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

i am trying to set basic open graph video properties for a web page (so that sharing a link to the page on facebook will allow a video to play in the timeline) and in order to do so need to create an app on facebook.

in the settings for the app there is a field called 'App Domains:'.  when i enter a domain in here and click 'save changes' the contents of the field are not saved.

this issue has been solved here:

[Facebook App Domain dissapears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616965/facebook-app-domain-dissapears)

however the solution was dependent on an interface that i think has now changed ie there is no 'website section' where i can enter a url.

can anyone please advise how i can make the 'app domain' stick upon saving.

thank you.

Comment: Have you to fill the field “Website with Facebook login” first.

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes, in the format `http://mysitename.com`, it is still not saving the field 'app domains'.

Comment: And what app domain value are you trying to set? Any error messages?

Comment: thank you again for your reply, the 'app domains' value i was trying to apply was a domain name.  it ended up however that this was not required to get the functionality i required working.  update posted above, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

for my purposes, ie getting a video to be embedded in a facebook timeline, the following has worked.  the facebook app only needed you to specify a url in the 'website with facebook login' field.  the 'app domains' field still did not stick upon save, but the functionality still worked.  if this is of assistance to anyone else, here is the code i used in a page that i wanted to share on facebook in order to show an embeddable video player:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="video title"/>
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="http://mysitename.com/movie.swf">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysitename.com/image.png"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysitename.com/page.html"/>
<meta property="og:video:height" content="240" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="320" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://mysitename.com/movie.mp4">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_app_id"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="your description here"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm not sure if those last references to an mp4 file work as a 'fallback' video type but they are in there just in case :).

helpful tools and resources used in this process:

- http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - shows you how facebook is processing the open graph information on your page and suggests fixes to any problems.
- http://www.mirovideoconverter.com - converts audio and video files
- http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter - converts audio and video files